# Trouble with fetching latitude and longitude data

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

i have bit strange problem.
I am fetching latitude and longitude of place in my php.
demo latitude and longitude are like this

```
Latitude 20º 24.002' N

Longitude 87º 18.135' W
```

The problem is because of `º` the data is not retrieved. how to get latitude with `º`?

Here is my query

```
$sql = "select * from tbl_site where sit_id =".$_GET[id];
```

After fetching data I have this array:-

```
{"item":{"sit_id":"3","sit_title":"title","sit_image":"img2.jpg","sit_zon_id":"1‌​","sit_access":"Boat","sit_rating":"5","sit_experience":"all divers","sit_latitude":null,"sit_longitude":null}}
```

Code that fetches from database and parses to JSON:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET[id]);
$stmt->execute();
$employee = $stmt->fetchObject(); $dbh = null;
echo '{"item":'. json_encode($employee) .'}';
```

Comment: Not retrieved from what? Also, please post the code too. The more you tell, the easier the help will come.

Comment: i am using services to fetch the data...so its just a simple query of select...

Comment: `º` will not prevent data from being retrieved from a database. Do you have this data in a string variable? if so, how are you trying to parse it?

Comment: Please put the valuable data in the question instead of in the comments. Also, parsing the data retrieved is most likely the key point in this, so the code of you doing that is what we are all waiting for :)

Comment: If the data retrieved from the database is that string you've quoted, then where is the latitude and longitude coming from?

Comment: both latitude and longitude are coming from where the other data is coming...

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius mind me i m coding simple select query dear

Comment: It's up to you whether you want us to help you or not. We are asking questions not because we do not have anything else what to do, but because we are trying to find the cause of your problem as fast as possible. Not providing us with what we ask isn't gonna help you :(

Comment: $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
 $stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET[id]);
 $stmt->execute();
 $employee = $stmt->fetchObject();  
 $dbh = null;
 echo '{"item":'. json_encode($employee) .'}';

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius above is my php code...but after json_encode latitude and longitude are not fetched...

Comment: @shwetdalal: edit the question instead of posting in the comments

Comment: To what character set is your table set?

Comment: Are you 100 % sure the latitude and longitude are in the db record? If so, what type is the column? (I presume string, but one can never be sure.)

Comment: @MartyMcVry ofcourse it is in db record. it has text datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First utf8_encode your php code than try to decode with java-script or string replace

Answer (score -2):

You may use [***GEOMETRY spatial extention***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) in this case to store lat,long.

to store a point on map, you can use `POINT(long,lat)`.

And, convert your latitude, longitude from degree to decimal.

So, your each point should look like:

```
POINT(20.xxxx, 87.xxxx);
```

Comment: And "need" is a harsh word... He could use that extension, but it's not absolutely necessary for it to work.
This, btw, doesn't solve OP's problem.